# Can't store JWT in Cookie with Express & Angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, cookies, jwt, mean-stack

I have been pulling my hair out the last couple of days. No matter how many google searches I make I can't find an answer so I come here as a last resort in hope of some help.

I am creating a full stack application on the MEAN stack. My login works. It is verifying that the email and password is matching a user's email and password in my database. Now I want to send a JWT token to my client so I can keep the user signed inn. I understand how JWT works and I have generated one already

```
 const ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "a random string";
 const payload = {"username": login_result[0].username}; 
 const accessToken = jwt.sign(payload, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
```

This is where my problems start. I want to store the token in a cookie, to prevent XSS attacks. I have tried all kinds of ways to store the JWT in a cookie. Most forums wrote that I should do

```
res.cookie('access_token', accessToken);
```

As I understand, this should automatically store the JWT in a cookie, on my client, under the name "access_token". However this does not work. When this line is in the code, nothing is happening. By "nothing is happening" I mean that the client code does not execute.

If a password/email is invalid, I return an error code.

```
if(res.msg == "403"){
        this.showLogErrorMsg = true;
      }
```

**This part works.**

The else statement looks like this

```
else {
    console.log("Valid username and password");
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:4200/profile";
}
```

Meaning, if the log in is wrong, it will print an error (and it does), if the log in is correct, they are suppose to get redirected. This does not work. It did work when I did

```
ret.json({"access_token":accessToken});
```

but does not work with

```
res.cookie('access_token', accessToken);
```

This is what I don't understand. It does not store the access_token in cookies and it does not execute the code inside the else statement. There are no error messages on my server or client. Further more, every guide or tutorial says to use the res.cookie, since I am using Express as my webserver.

I have even tried adding the following options:

```
    res.cookie('access_token', accessToken,{domain: domain, path: '/',httpOnly:false, 
               secure:false,sameSite:false});
```

The solution is to either, somehow make the res.cookies work, which I really want to do due to it being "what everybody else is using" and it seems really chill. Or, send the JWT token as res.json and then save the token to a cookie in angular. However, does this open you up for XSS? And if not, how can I save something to a cookie in angular?

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Can you please confirm that the `Set-Cookie` header is properly received by the client? (Dev tools > Network)

Comment: I do not belive that there is a Set-Cookie header. I am not very versed in the networking part so I will link some screenshots. 
This is what happens on the network part when I try to log in with correct username/password:
http://prntscr.com/tsppq6
http://prntscr.com/tspq1i
http://prntscr.com/tspq55

May I ask, what is the Set-Cookie header?

Comment: `Set-Cookie` is the header that tells the client to save information for the domain. When you use express and call `res.cookie('COOKIE_NAME',...)` it (should) generate a `Set-Cookie` header to carry and set that data to the client. To test this create the most simplest endpoint and set a cookie (remove middlewares is the header isn't set).

Comment: @Daniel I am a big uncertain how to "create the most simplest endpoint and set a cookie (remove middlewares is the header isn't set)". By this you mean, create a webserver with express(backend) and send a cookie to a random frontend component(client) without any "fancy" verifiction against my DB?

Comment: yep. If your issue is setting the Cookie try to reduce the problem to its simplest form

Comment: @Daniel thank you! I will get back to you ASAP. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Daniel I have gotten some more information and insight into this. 
1) I created a simple version of this where I only use httpclient on frotnend and express on the backend. It still won't set the cookie. I googled around and it seems this might be an issue with the HTTP client from angular?_import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';_
I am very uncertain about how to even fix this. I tried adding this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:3500/test",{withCredentials : true});
Since people said withCredentials would help, it did not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic `express` app that sets, unset, and displays cookies.

- set `GET /login`
- unset `GET /logout`
- display `GET /`

This is not dependent on the client (angular)

```
# main.js
const express = require('express')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

const app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

const port = 3000
const accessToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.cookies)
});

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.cookie('access_token', accessToken, { path: '/', httpOnly: true, sameSite: "strict" })
    res.send('"access_token" cookies was set !')
});

app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    res.cookie('access_token', accessToken, { maxAge: 0 })
    res.send('"access_token" cookies was unset !')
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. It seems that the problem is that, I need to use a GET request to set the cookie? If I change your code to POST (like my code is) it will add the SET-COOKIE header, but not display the cookie. However, if I use GET request, it sets the cookie in my browser. Anyway I can do this with a POST request?

Comment: With further testing, it doesn't seem like it always set the cookie on a GET request either. I have to go into network and click on the package before it wants to display the cookie... I can see the Set-Cookie in my header, but I can't see it in my Application > Cookies, before I click on the package itself.

Comment: I uploaded a GIF that shows the full flow https://wetransfer.com/downloads/350a1ed0290ed8d5597257269f03844b20200811113543/57bafd